# jQuery Amigo-sorter drag and drop library not working properly

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I have a problem with Amigo-sorter library. I am dynamically adding LI tags into UL when I check the checkbox, subsequently I want to sort by drag and drop. It works fine on PC but when I use mobile phone. When I first click on whatever checkbox it adds the LI tag and is dragable. But next clicking on other checkboxes does not do anything.
Any ideas what the issue is please?

Please see the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2vf8rgc7/

```
<html>
<section class="wrapper">
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" value="January">January</input>
    </div>
     <div>
       <input type="checkbox" value="February">February</input>
    </div>
     <div>
       <input type="checkbox" value="March">March</input>
    </div>
    </section>

   <ul class="sorter">
   </ul>
</html>

// javascript
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('change', '.wrapper', function(ev){
      let elem = document.createElement("li");
      elem.innerHTML = "<span>" + ev.target.value + "</span>";
      document.querySelector(".sorter").appendChild(elem);

       // after each change run the drag and drop function
      $('ul.sorter').amigoSorter({
        li_helper: "li_helper",
        li_empty: "empty",
        onTouchStart : function() {},
        onTouchMove : function() {},
        onTouchEnd : function() {}
        });

    });

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it, the problem is that there is a preventDefault within the Amigo-sorter function which makes next change event not working. If I remove it it works, but I yet need to figure out how to stop simultaneous scrolling when I drag. 
I am thinking of something like checking the position of where I click (touch) and if the position is inside the UL only then run preventDefault.